# Performance comparison of lookup versus mapPartitions with dicts

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, is it better to use `lookup` after `partitionBy` from a performance perspective, versus something like:

```
sc.parallelize(range(4000000))                                 \
  .mapPartitions( lambda l: [ dict( [ (i,i) for i in l ] ) ] ) \
  .map( lambda d: d.get(33, None) )                            \
  .collect()
```

My objective is to emulate a distributed hashmap with fast lookups.

Comment: I don't see a Distributed HashMap here. You are creating a RDD of dictionaries and then trying to get the 33 element from the dictionary...

Comment: eliasah Correct, I'm trying to emulate one, not build one.

Comment: The RDD is already distributed and has it's own hash function, so what are you trying to emulate? What are you trying to do is not clear, no offense, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use `partitionBy` and then `lookup` or to create for each partition a `HashMap` which stores all occurring elements strongly depends on your data. Depending on the key cardinality and the data distribution, either the former or latter solution can be advantageous.

However, in the general case, I would refrain from using `lookup` too often, because it is a linear operation in the size of the partition. When you call `lookup` on partitioned data then it will traverse completely the respective partition to find all elements with a matching key. For this operation a data structure with a better lookup complexity might be beneficial.

If you really want to implement a distributed hash map, then I guess you should partition your data, calling distinct on it and then insert the remaining data in a hash map for faster querying.

Comment: My objective is to emulate a distributed hashmap with fast lookups. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @FailingSkies, I think that it strongly depends on your data, e.g. cardinality of keys and data distribution. Furthermore, you have to specify the semantics properly. In your solution you won't obtain the same results as with `lookup` if one of your partition contains elements with the same key. If you really want to implement a distributed hash map, then I guess you should partition your data, calling distinct on it and then insert the remaining data in a hash map for faster querying. The problem of `lookup` is that it's a linear operation which traverses through the whole partition.

Comment: thanks, this is the answer I was looking for "lookup is [...] a linear operation which traverses through the whole partition". Please formulate a proper answer with it so I can give you credits.